# How to find the maximum by comparing previous value?

Tags: python, arrays, database, max

I have a huge data set & complex code that it takes so much time if I am trying to find the maximum by appending all intermediate results and compare. So I want to implement algorithm to find the maximum by comparing previous value.
my algorithm goes like,

```
for i in range(len(y)):
  oldmax = y[0]
  if oldmax >= y[i]:
    pass
  else:
    new_max = y[i]
```

then I want to store this newmax and compare with next string y[i+1] and go on (Only the maximum value should survive at the end).
But I am not sure how to set this new_max to be something to be compared in the next loop. For example, let y = [3,1,5,6,4]. Since the y[0] is greater than y[1], it will pass until it meets 5. But since 6 and 4 are also greater than 3, the new_max ends up being 4 which is the last value.

How should I fix the code? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you use the function `max()` ? That block of cold can just be a line: `new_max = max(y)`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use one variable and compare until `length - 1`? Also, you keep resetting `oldmax` to the first element on every iteration, causing inaccurate results. Set it's initial value but don't change it:

```
max_value = y[0]
for i in range(len(y) - 1):
    if max_value <= y[i + 1]
        max_value = y[i + 1]
```

Now what does is just has one variable, `max_value` which has an initial value of the first element. The loop goes from first element to `length - 1`, due to the accessing of element `i + 1`. If the max is less than the next value, reassign max to the next value. I also eliminated the extra if that did nothing and only checked if it was larger.

---

You can get rid of all the code above by just using the builtin [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function which takes in any iterable and returns the maximum value:

```
max_value = max(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

***If*** you want to do it like that, you don't need to work with `index`, which will probably be slightly slower on huge data.

You can simply do:

```
newmax = y[0]
for new in y:
    newmax = new if new > newmax else newmax
```

You'd need to do a test on huge data though to see if this is fast enough.

Comment: The conditional expression always evaluates to `new` !